# Ubuntu on macbook won't boot from USB

Tags: ubuntu, boot, live-usb, macintosh, troubleshooting

I cannot boot Ubuntu from my macbook. I have tried the official Ubuntu walkthrough for creating a USB boot stick (located here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx  ) and it will not work. I get to step 10 (turn off computer. Turn computer on and hold alt/option) and it goes to a menu where I should be able to select Ubuntu but the only option available is "Macintosh HD". I have also tried this with a boot CD and using rEFIt but to no avail.

My macbook is an early 2008 model. I am trying to avoid partitioning my HD because I just want to *try* Ubuntu. After all, partitioning is not even required in the official walkthrough (see above link). Perhaps I have changed my preferences at some point? Or disabled a utility? Also, I'm using an 8Gb USB thumb drive.

I *have* tried partitioning that and still nothing. I don't really know what question to ask here... Like I said, I want to avoid partitioning my mac HD. Also, it must be Ubuntu... not any other distribution. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like the USB stick is not recognized by your macbook as a boot device. Not all sticks can be made bootable. Try another stick.

Comment: Booting from a CD/DVD is _usually_ less problematic than booting from a USB. Since you had no success booting a Linux CD using rEFIt you might like to give [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) a try instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check your BIOS settings. Is booting from USB allowed and what is the order for boot devices? Changing / verifying boot device settings should come first, IMO.